# A fair dice is to be rolled $n$ times. Find the probability of not getting three consecutive sixes.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, contest-math

> A fair dice is to be rolled $n$ times. Find the probability of not getting three consecutive sixes. (Here $12664665$ or $12346522$ is a valid result while $12666555$ or $66664256$ isn't.)

The problem is inspired from [this problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1990_AIME_Problems/Problem_9). I think the problem can be solved by case working. But I am not interested in that kind of solution. Rather I am interested in a solution that uses recurrence relations like [this solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1990_AIME_Problems/Problem_9#Solution_2_.28Recursion.29) of the original problem. I've thought of a way to solve the problem which is not complete:

The main concern of solving the problem is to find the number of ways to arrange the numbers $1$ to $6$ such that no three sixes are consecutive. Now, we change all the digits which are not $6$ into $0$. For example, if we get $1266564$, we will change this as $0066060$. Let $S_n$ be the number of such valid results that contain $0$ and $6$ only.   ​
Now, if the first rolled dice gets a $0$ then there are $n-1$ rolls still left. But any of the results will be similar to one of the configurations of $S_{n-1}$.
If the first rolled dice gets a $6$ and the second rolled dice gets a $0$, then using the same logic above we get that there $S_{n-2}$ ways of getting a valid result.
If the first rolled dice gets a $6$ and the second rolled dice gets a $6$, then the third rolled dice will get a $0$ for the result to be valid. So, there will be $S_{n-3}$ ways of getting the result.
Hence, we get a recurrence relation that is: $S_n=S_{n-1}+S_{n-2}+S_{n-3}$. Now, my idea was to change all $0$s into $1,2,3,4$ or $5$. But I think that's not possible or that will be too complicated as there will be too many cases.

So, I need a solution to the problem that uses recurrence relations.

Comment: Note that any (sufficiently long) string without a $666$ must end in one of $X, X6$ or $X66$ where $X\neq 6$.

Comment: @lulu I think I showed the same idea. I took the beginning part instead of the ending part.

Comment: But I don't see the advantage in setting $X$ to $0$.  There are $5$ options for $X$.  Hence there are $5$ cases for each of the three possible endings.

Comment: Note in particular that, while the recursion you provide really isn't relevant as it stands, it is easy to modify it to get the correct recursion.  Just remember that there are $5$ cases for each of the three possible endings.

Comment: @Unknown you can ask where you do not understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a beautiful question to make use of the power of Goulden-Jackson method ! (I want to especially thank to @Markus Scheuer for this beautiful method)

I am putting here a link for you : https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036 ,you can learn more about it.

According to the article , our bad words are $666$.

Then , our alphabet is $V= \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

$$A(x)= \frac{1}{1-dx-weight(C)}$$ with $d=|V|=6$ and $weight(C) = weight(C[666])$

> Lets calculate $weight(C[000])$ according to the paper such that
>
> $weight(C[666])= -x^3 - (x +x^2)weight(C[666])$
>
> So , $weight(C[666]) = \frac{-x^3}{(1+x +x^2)} $

Hence ,  $$weight(C) = \frac{-x^3}{1+x+x^2} $$

Then , $$A(x) = \frac{1}{1-6x -\frac{-x^3}{1+x+x^2}} = \frac{1+x+x^2}{1-5x-5x^2-5x^3}$$

Now , we will turn this fraction into recurrence relation. See for instance theorem 4.1.1 in Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. I by R. P. Stanley. (https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/enumerative-combinatorics-vol-i)

$$\frac{1+x+x^2}{1-5x-5x^2-5x^3} \rightarrow a_{n+3}-5a_{n+2}-5a_{n+1}-5a_{n}=0$$

Then , $$a_n=5a_{n-1} + 5a_{n-2} +5a_{n-3}$$

Moreover , we can find the reseult of any string by generating functions such that https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2Bx+%2B+x%5E2%29+%2F+%281-5x-5x%5E2+-5x%5E3%29

$$\frac{1+x+x^2}{1-5x-5x^2-5x^3}=1+6x+36x^2 + \color{blue}{215x^3} + 1285x^4 + ...$$

This means that there are $215$ different string of lenght $3$ do not contain three consecutive $6$

Moreover , the sample space is $6^n$

You can say that $$\frac{a_n=5a_{n-1} + 5a_{n-2} +5a_{n-3}}{6^n}$$
where $a_0 =1 , a_1 =6 , a_2=36 , a_3=215$

Answer (score 2):

For your dice rolls, let

- $A_n$ be the probability of $n$ acceptable roll sequences which do not end in $6$
- $B_n$ be the probability of $n$ acceptable roll sequences which end in one $6$
- $C_n$ be probability of $n$ acceptable roll sequences which end in two $6$s

You have

- $A_{n+1}=\frac56 (A_n+B_n+C_n)$ since any of five out of six results can be appended
- $B_{n+1}=\frac16 A_n$ since you need one $6$
- $C_{n+1}=\frac16 B_n$ since you need a second $6$ and so $C_{n+1}=\frac1{36}A_{n-1}$
- starting with $A_0=1,B_0=0,C_0=0$

The first three of those imply $A_{n+1}=\frac56 A_n+\frac5{36}A_{n-1}+\frac5{216}A_{n-2}$ at least for $n\ge 2$

You want $p_n= A_n+B_n+C_n$ as the sum of probabilities

so $p_{n}=\frac65 A_{n+1} = A_n+\frac16A_{n-1}+\frac1{36}A_{n-2}$ and $A_{n+1}=\frac56 p_{n}$,
i.e. $$p_n = \frac56 p_{n-1}+ \frac5{36}p_{n-2}+ \frac5{216}p_{n-3}
$$ at least for $n\ge 3$, and clearly $p_0=p_1=p_2=1$ to start you off since you cannot get $666$ with three rolls.  If you had wanted $S_n$ as the number of  rather than the probability, you would have $S_n = 5( S_{n-1}+ S_{n-2}+ S_{n-3})$ and $p_n=\frac{S_n}{6^n}$

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out the hint in the comments, we want to count $S_n$, the number of strings with no $666$.

Since each "good" string of length $n≥3$ must end in one of $X, X6, X66$ where $X\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, we see that $$S_n=5(S_{n-1}+S_{n-2}+S_{n-3})$$  at least for $n≥4$. if we set $S_0=1$ then this holds for $n≥3$, but since it is easy to deduce that $S_1=6, S_2=36, S_3=215$ we really don't need to. However you do it, there is no difficulty computing $S_5$.

In principle we could solve this in closed form, but the characteristic polynomial $x^3=5x^2+5x+5$ does not have terrible pleasant roots, so this is not practical.  As it happens, only one root has norm $>1$ so one might at least hope for useful asymptotic formulas.  For instance, it is easy to see that $$\frac {S_n}{S_{n-1}}\to 5.9766$$
where $5.9766$ is, approximately, the large real root of the cubic.